# How to detect if a location provider is reachable or unreachable?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-location

I am developing an Android application in which I need to Log if there is a change in status of the provider. If the wifi connection is not reachable there should be log entry with the change in status.

```
provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(crit, true);
isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        Log.i("GPSTracker", "isGPSEnabled-" + isGPSEnabled);
        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        Log.i("GPSTracker", "isNetworkEnabled-" + isNetworkEnabled);
        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {

            //Log.i("GPSTracker", "provider=" + provider);
            this.canGetLocation1 = true;
            // First get location from Network Provider
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                Log.i("GPSTracker", "line 65 network enabled");
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                Log.i("GPSTracker", "gps enabled line 82");
                if (location == null) {
                    Log.i("GPSTracker",
                            "location is null. request gps provider");
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    switch (status) {
    case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
        Log.v("GPSTracker", "Status Changed: Out of Service");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Status Changed: Out of Service",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
        Log.v("GPSTracker", "Status Changed: Temporarily Unavailable");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Status Changed: Temporarily Unavailable",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
        Log.v("GPSTracker", "Status Changed: Available");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Status Changed: Available",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    }
}
```

Now I tried to walk away from wifi until there is no wifi signal. Now I am expecting a change in status call back which is not happening. I see no log or toast message appearing.

Comment: when you requested location updates, how often did you request for them to be received ? did you request location updates ?

Comment: @LenaBru  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 0, this);

Comment: and who is your provider ?

Comment: @LenaBru I am just creating an object for provider but not using it for getting location. Updated addition code